# Closure of $\ell^2$ in the space of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Using the product topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^\omega$, is $\ell^2$ (the space of real square summable sequences) a dense subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^\omega$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ell_2$ contains all sequences with only finitely many non-zero components: $$D = \{(x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^\omega: |\{n: x_n \neq 0\}| < \aleph_0 \}\subset \ell_2$$

$D$ is clearly dense in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, so $\ell_2$ is as well.

The same holds for $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^\omega$ in the product topology. (This contains $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as a dense subset and "dense in dense is dense".

So the closures are the whole space in both cases.